# Softbank Pepper robot with Naoqi - camera livefeed latency with Python

Tags: python, camera, frame-rate, latency, pepper

I'm programming the Softbanks Pepper Robot with Python. I want to have a livefeed coming from the camera of the robot. But the function

```
 pepperImage = self.video_service.getImageRemote(self.nameId)
```

is very slow, and uses over 300ms getting the image. With a livefeed, this is only 2-3fps, which is very bad. Im using the Naoqi library, and network speed shouldn't be a issue, my PC, router and Pepper is in the same room, and Pepper is the only task for the router. 
I'm using Python 2 with Pycharm.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: softbank has an excellent community on their website, please take a look at  https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/ja/node/1160

Comment: v.coder: that community website is archived (you can see old posts but can't create new ones), stack overflow is probably a better place for getting answers.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a decent network, you should be able to have at least 10fps in wifi and 25fps in ethernet depending of the resolution.
Here are some ideas:

- If currently both in wifi, put your computer in ethernet
- Try reducing the size of the image (do you really need color ?)
- Try reducing the size of the image (do you really need 4VGA or HD ?)
- Stop some other processing potentially using camera (on board face detection/recognition, image analysis, autonomous life, choregraphe...)

Good luck...

You can also refer to the documentation from Softbank, which tells you the limitations: [See here...](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/vision/alvideodevice.html#performances-and-limitations)